# unrecognized rule error in lex {lineo++;}

Tags: compiler-errors, lex, cc

I've got some errors in my lex code, maybe someone know what i made wrong ...

```
16    %%
17    {ws}  {/*no action and no return */}
18    {}    
19    {newline} {lineo++;}
20    {number}  {tokenval=atoi(yytext); return(NUM);}
21    {id}      {
22          int p = 0;
23          p = lookup(yytext);
24          if (p == 0) 
25          p = insert (yytext, ID);
26      tokenval = p;
27      return symtable[p].token;
28    
29    }
30    
31    <<EOF>>   {return DONE;}
32      {tokenval = NONE; return yytext[0];}
33    
34    
35    %%
```

I'm newbie in this kind of technology, and I spend on it many of time but without any positive result. Below errors from the console:

```
new.l:21: unrecognized rule
new.l:28: unrecognized rule
new.l:28: unrecognized rule
new.l:36: EOF encountered inside an action
new.l:36: unrecognized rule
new.l:36: fatal parse error
make: *** [lex.yy.c] Error 1
```

When I'm deleted that lines of code whoes bad (lines: 21-32) I've got that error:

> new.l:19:2: error: ‘lineo’ undeclared (first use in this function) 
>   {newline} {lineo++;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Line 18 (`{}`) is just wrong; flex will treat that as a pattern, not an action.
2. You probably meant to write `lineno` (that is, a way of typing "Line Nº" which is an abbreviation for "line number".) But did you declare it somewhere? Or did you intend to use `yylineno`?
3. Did you define `{id}`? The error message suggests you didn't, but you didn't paste your definitions.
4. In line 32, the pattern for the default rule is `.`:

   `.   {tokenval = NONE; return yytext[0];}`
5. Have you read the handy [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)?

In addition to the above, as a replacement to point 3, the definition:

```
id      {letter}({letter} | {digit})*
```

is incorrect because *regular expressions cannot include unquoted whitespace*. You need to write that as

```
id      {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
```

Comment: This is all my code: https://gist.github.com/Epredator/11263395
. I was trying make some changes, but I still have no idea how it works. I use this manual to Flex: http://neo.dmcs.p.lodz.pl/tk/flex/flex.pdf maybe is not new version but still works ;)

Comment: @Epredator: I added one more error to correct. Also, your final code block is not valid `C` because the function `lexan` you define doesn't have an explicit return type; it probably should have been written `int lexan() { return yylex(); }` but it's redundant because you can just call `yylex` directly. The manual is indeed for an older version, and I'd recommend using a newer one such as the one I linked to. But it should be ok.